# How to catch exception for "Can only throw this exception type from VisualForce or Aura context"

Tags: apex, exception

I have an apex class that does not interact with Aura. Sometimes I get the error "Can only throw this exception type from VisualForce or Aura context". I'm looking to see if I can catch that exception. I haven't been able to yet.

I've tried the following snippet but my code never gets the exception. Is there a way to catch it?

```
 catch(System.LimitException l){
       if(l.getMessage().contains('Can only throw this exception type from 
       VisualForce or Aura context')){ 
       System.debug('System LimitException ' +l.getMessage());
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Limit exceptions can't be caught

Comment: ahh okay thanks for verifying!

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/299265/can-only-throw-this-exception-type-from-visualforce-or-aura-context-error-on-s